# Biking layer in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, features, mapping

I would like to add a biking layer like the one available in Google Maps (under Map details, see example below) but couldn't find any guide or information about its availability in Google Earth Engine. How can I do this?

[image: Biking layer in Google Maps]

Answer (score 0):

Google doesn't make their biking data available for use outside of the Google Maps interface.  You'd have to get the data from somewhere else (OSM?) and upload it yourself.